# Java Client Server Desktop app database

Tags: java, database, server, client, desktop

I was given a mini project in which i have to develop two applications one for a client and another one for a user. It essential to use Java language. One more thing client side should have the database(any database type). The most important thing it should be the desktop application which should run on two different pc.( i have mac with eclipse). The title of the project "Warehouse management" where records made on client pc should be recorded and seen by client side on common db. I need the most simple approach because it is just small mini project. Thanks.

Comment: Check out this link to know how to ask [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: "one for a client and another one for a user" - don't you mean one client application and one server application? The user normally uses the client. Besides that what you describe looks like there are multiple instances of the client which share a common database. A very simple approach (which has its own caveats) would be to have the client applications access the database directly via JDBC. Then organize how they should interact with each other when it comes to database access.

Comment: Also by "any database type" do you mean it's up to you to select one or should the user/client be able to select? If the latter then note that that's not simple (although doable).

Comment: my mistake of course client server, by any database i mean up to me to choose any databese